# A way to refresh a form page from another form page?

Tags: winforms

I have a Win form application (VS 2010 / C#) and I'm trying to figure out how to refresh pages without a refresh button. Currently I can refresh a page (basically to reset the data bindings) with a refresh button containing code something like this (this.refresh() does not seem to work for some reason):

```
this.Hide();
AccountSettings AS = new AccountSettings();
AS.ShowDialog();
```

An example I have is a page with numerous settings including data grids with CellClick events. When I click a cell I can make changes to a database. I hit close to go back to the Settings page but the only way for me to see the changes are to refresh() the page via the button.

So the short of it is, is there any way to refresh a form page from another form page?
For instance, when I click the Save button or close the child window.

Comment: You'll have to update the binding source.  The grid will update itself from that.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe pass the original form as an argument to the second form:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
```

And in Form2:

```
Form1 frm1;
public Form2(Form1 frm1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.frm1 = frm1;
}
```

And then have in Form2:

```
frm1.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Refresh on winform controls repaints the control itself.  I find it useful to create a method that just loads my controls with the proper data, and then call it as necessary. (Including Form load)

```
private void ResetData()
    {
      //code to update settings
    }
```

If you are showing the form that is closing as a dialog also you can take advantage of that, and check the status of the dialog instead of just opening it.

```
Form2 dlg = new Form2();
if (dlg.ShowDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
    //code that updates your data
    ResetData();
}
```

If its not a dialog there are a few things you could do and how your application works would make one method better than others.  Here is just one example.

If your changes are something you don't need access to data from the other window to update you can handle the closed event of the form you create.

Create a class level variable to hold the form that is opened, so that you can also remove the event handlers you create:

```
private Form2 frm;
```

To create an instance of the form, and add the close event handler:

```
    frm = new Form2();
    frm.FormClosed += OnForm2Closed;
```

The event handler method:

```
private void OnForm2Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    ResetData();
    frm.FormClosed -= OnForm2Closed;
}
```